# Cutting Down Repetitive code to Avoid "Procedure Too Large" error

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have some VBA code that essentially replaces a Filter Field in a PivotTable, but because the current excel spreadsheet has hundreds of PivotTables, I'm reaching to a point where the VBA doesn't work with Procedure too large.

Problem is I don't know how to decrease the repetition - any assistance would be certainly appreciated.

Code below:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Intersect(Target, Range("P6:P7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim pt As PivotTable
        Dim Field As PivotField
        Dim NewCat As String

        Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Booking").PivotTables("PivotTable8")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
        NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

        With pt
             Field.ClearAllFilters
             Field.CurrentPage = NewCat


        End With

        Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Booking").PivotTables("PivotTable6")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
        NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

        With pt
             Field.ClearAllFilters
             Field.CurrentPage = NewCat


        End With

        Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Booking").PivotTables("PivotTable20")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
        NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

        With pt
             Field.ClearAllFilters
             Field.CurrentPage = NewCat


        End With

        Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Booking").PivotTables("PivotTable7")
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
        NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

        With pt
             Field.ClearAllFilters
             Field.CurrentPage = NewCat


     'Keeps on repeating for about 200 more PivotTables in Various Sheets

 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Use a slicer for the company code!!! Or failing that at least Use foreach loop to loop through all pivot tables in the workbook setting the value to cell p6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change all the pivot tables on that sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Intersect(Target, Range("P6:P7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim pt As PivotTable, NewCat As String, s

        NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

        For Each s In Array("Pivot Booking", "Pivot Transaction", _
                                             "Pivot Level Segment")

            For Each pt In Worksheets(s).PivotTables
                With pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
                    .ClearAllFilters
                    .CurrentPage = NewCat
                End With
            Next pt

        Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I loop this to add another 2 Sheets? ("Pivot Transaction" and "Pivot Level Segment")?

So far I tried looping the sub by repeating the whole code and It didn't work. Also tried creating subroutines but that also didn't work. 

Apologies - my VBA-fu is definitely not up to scratch.

Comment: shouldn't it be safer to add `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the beginning and turn it back to `True` by the end of it? Or `ClearAllFilters` method and `CurrentPage `property setting don't trigger `Worksheet_Change` event when acting on any pivot table on that same worksheet ?

Comment: @user3598756 - yes, it would make sense to do that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all - the complete code that has worked is as per below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("P6:P7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim pt As PivotTable, NewCat As String, s

    NewCat = Worksheets("Trending&Benchmarking").Range("P6").Value

    For Each s In Array("Pivot Booking", "Pivot Transaction", "Pivot Level Segment", "Pivot YoY TransactionGraph")

        For Each pt In Worksheets(s).PivotTables
            With pt.PivotFields("Company Code")
                .ClearAllFilters
                .CurrentPage = NewCat
            End With
        Next pt

    Next s

ErrorHandler:

  Debug.Print Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
  Resume ErrorExit

ErrorExit:

  Application.EnableEvents = True

   Exit Sub


End Sub
```